# A way to Python program unilaterally transmit a message to another program written in another language

Tags: python, linux, http, system

I'm trying to write a Python program that will unilaterally transmit a message to another program that can be written in any programming language. These messages can be transmitted several times per second. The sender is constantly sending messages and a receiver is constantly waiting for a message. There may be several programs to which messages are transmitted and they will be written by other people. All this will work within a single Linux environment.

That is, what method of transmitting messages between programs is suitable if a Python program transmits messages, and a recipient can be programmed in Python, Java, maybe even in other programming language?

I tried using the HTTP API, that is, the sending program calls the HTTP API of the receiving program. But it looks wrong, because both programs work on the same computer, there is no point in using a web server...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interprocess communication in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920858/interprocess-communication-in-python)

Comment: Whats wrong with HTTP? It's a way for programs to communicate! But in this case raw sockets might work best.

Comment: JonSG, thanks, but a receiver can be written not only in Python. 
TheTridentGuy, thanks. So I see 3 options here: raw sockets, a message broker or HTTP API.

Comment: @TobiasHübner the Unix socket sender (python) does not care about how the receiver is implemented.

Comment: (aside: I would have voted to close this as "too broad", not "off-topic"; it's clearly not suited here, but for a different reason than the close vote landed on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your case you can try [a message-broker software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker) like [ZeroMQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZeroMQ) (libraries are available for Python, Java, C, C++, C#, Ruby, Dart, Go, NodeJS, Perl, Rust, F#, Haskell, Erlang).

Comment: What do you think about raw sockets?

Comment: It's a good option, too. You will need more code and there will be more chance to make a mistake. There are a lot of libraries for a message-broker software for almost all programming languages, so I think it would the best option in your case.

Comment: Thumbs-up for the 0mq recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a message broker or a common data format, such as [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), on a [RESTful API.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49843322/17396476)

Comment: You need a common data format even if you _do_ have a message broker managing transport; it's "and", not "or".